# How to change one line of code in a block of code from linux command line?

Tags: grep, sed, awk

I have a change I need to make across multiple different sites and may need to make again in the future, so I'd like to put it in a shell script. Essentially I want to find a specific class block in a css file, find one of its attributes and change the value of that attribute.

So for example:

```
.some-id {
  some-arbitrary-properties
  property-i-want: old-value
  maybe-some-more-properties
}
```

I want to only change old-value in property-i-want, and only if it's in .some-id.

I'm very comfortable with grep, but it only works one line at a time. I'm somewhat less comfortable with sed, but I haven't seen any way to do this without a deterministic set of properties. For instance, I could have sed replace the entire block. But I want to leave any other properties in the block alone.

I'd rather not use perl or python, but I can. I'd like to keep it short, because it's going in a script of one-liners.

Answer (score 1):

Write a small program using a CSS library in whatever language. You mentioned Perl, perhaps [CSS::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/CSS::Tiny).

One-liners are overrated, can be difficult to read. Selecting a style, reading a property, changing a property if a condition, these are more than one step.